# Gulp - After versioning my images with "gulp-rev", how can I update their references in a CSS in a different location to the outputted image files?

Tags: node.js, gulp, frontend, gulp-rev

Using **Gulp** and **Node.js**, I'm creating a proof of concept that generates sprites from folders of images, then versions the generated sprites so they have unique file names for cache busting purposes.

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev to version the sprites (*this works!*), but I'm having trouble updating CSS files with references to the images. There are some tools that I have looked at for this purpose but I haven't been able to get them to work. The two that I have look at are:

https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace

**(Seems fully featured by can't figure it out)**

and..

https://github.com/galkinrost/gulp-rev-css-url

**(Got working but couldn't separate the destination for the revisioned images files and the updated CSS with the new images names)**

Essentially I want to grab all the images from **`gulp-image-versioning-poc/images/sprites/*.png`** and then version them, put the resulting images in **`gulp-image-versioning-poc/dist/`** and update the references to those images in **`gulp-image-versioning-poc/css/*.css`**

I've created a simplified example of what I currently have here:

https://github.com/olthof/gulp-image-versioning-poc

If anyone could help me tackling this problem I would be very grateful!!!

Comment: Hi Tim, did you manage to find a workaround ? I'm also considering several gulp asset versioning scripts atm.